# Why are 1,0 differential forms $\mathbb C$-linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

I am struggling to understand a passage from Claire Voisin’s book on Hodge Theory.

In page 53, at the beginning of the section 2.3.1, there is the following assertion:

> “…the bundle $\Omega_X^{1,0}$ of complex differential forms of type 1,0, i.e. $\mathbb C$-linear forms…”

[image: page 53]

I don’t see why forms of type 1,0 should be C-linear.

Maybe I don’t understand correctly what $\Omega_X^{1,0}$ is. To me it is supposed to be $\hom_\mathbb R(T^{1,0}_X, \mathbb C)$.

Am I wrong here?
If not, why is $\hom_\mathbb R(T^{1,0}_X, \mathbb C)$ equal to $\hom_\mathbb C(T^{1,0}_X, \mathbb C)$?

UPDATE: In Page 64/65 of the same book the author mentions the same result but with vectors spaces instead of vector bundles, and there is explicit that $\hom_\mathbb R (V,\mathbb C)$ splits as a sum of $\mathbb C$-linear forms and $\mathbb C$-antilinear forms, that correspond to the forms of type 1,0; 0,1.

[image: page 64]

[image: page 65]

Comment: Usually $(1, 0)$ forms are defined to be complex-linear, e.g., $dz = dx + i\, dy$ is of type $(1, 0)$, but $dx$ and $dy$ are not; is there something elsewhere that suggests $\operatorname{hom}_{\mathbf{R}}(T^{1,0}_{X}, \mathbf{C})$?

Comment: I added a photo for context, I think that $\Omega_X^{1,0}$ is $\hom_\mathbb R (T_{X,\mathbb C}, \mathbb C)$. Otherwise it would make no sense to say: “complex differential forms of type 1,0, i.e. C-linear “ If everything is already C-linear

Comment: Did you mean $\hom_\mathbb R (T_{X,\mathbb C}, \mathbb C)$ is $\Omega_{X,\Bbb{C}}$?

Comment: You're dealing with the complexified tangent bundle, so everything is over $\Bbb C$. The issue is going to be with interpreting $\Omega^{0,1}_X$: Does it act on holomorphic tangent vectors or on anti-holomorphic tangent vectors? This is a big confusion in complex geometry (and I've written answers to questions about this elsewhere on this site). When you're thinking of the hermitian metric on the holomorphic tangent bundle, you think of $d\bar z(v)$ as $\overline{dz(v)}$; when you're doing differential forms, you want $d\bar z$ to be dual to $\partial/\partial\bar z$.

Comment: Yes, I meant \Omega_{X,C}

Comment: I don’t understand how metrics are related to my problem. And I am pretty sure that at least $\Omega_{X,\mathbb C}$ are the real linear forms with complex values. In page 64/65, of the same book, they mention the same kind of argument but for vector spaces, and there is clear that we are taking real linear stuff.

Comment: $\hom_\mathbb R (T_{X,\mathbb C}, \mathbb C)$ decomposes as $\hom_\mathbb C (T_{X,\mathbb C}, \mathbb C)\oplus \overline{\hom_\mathbb C (T_{X,\mathbb C}, \mathbb C)}$. The first term is given (locally) by forms of the form $\omega=\sum_{j=1}^n f_j(z) dz_j$ with $z$ an holomorphic chart. A tangent vector $v$ at $p$ is represented by a curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to X,\gamma(0)=p,\gamma'(0)=v$. Then $z_j$ is an holomorphic function $X\to \Bbb{C}$ around $p$ and $\omega(v)=\sum_{j=1}^n f_j(z) (z_j\circ \gamma)'(0)$ is $\Bbb{C}$-linear in $v$.